# Gradle output is missing in Android Studio 2.2 (latest version)

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated my Android Studio to latest version 2.2. Then i can't able to see any gradle task output logs.

Below picture is i'm trying to get SHA-1 finger print key from gradle task **singingReport** .

Note : Previous Android Studio 2.1 is working fine.

Is this Android studio related issue ? Has anyone got similar problem like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out there has some changes on gradle version 2.14 (Android studio release note).

> Improves build performance by adopting a new default packaging
>   pipeline which handles zipping, signing, and zipaligning in one task.
>   You can revert to using the older packaging tools by adding
>   android.useOldPackaging=true to your gradle.properties file.

Here is complete detail [LINK](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions)

So now i can able to get the output data by enabling old packing style **android.useOldPackaging=true** in gradle.properties.